# Since today: Google 500 Error

Tags: google-oauth

I get 500 Errors when I redirect my users to the OAuth Endpoint from Europe. Has anything changed? It worked for several months

Comment: The URL looks like this: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fxxx.com%3A4200%2Fauth%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback&scope=email%20profile&client_id=xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com . I use https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth/commit/82b2b09eac9f62eb9e990f8baa0e77d5db5679ee

Comment: without your code and the actual error message we cant help you fix your problem. I can tell you that I haven't had any problems with Oauth in Europe today nor am I aware of any outages.

Comment: The error message is pretty generic. "500. That's an error. That's all we know.". The code that does the request is https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth/blob/82b2b09eac9f62eb9e990f8baa0e77d5db5679ee/lib/passport-google-oauth/oauth2.js

Comment: I had similar issue Google OAuth right now - it sometimes returns "internal_failure" on auth token refresh. Probably they have some problems. The same code work an hour ago and for few months before now.

Comment: Thanks for your report @Vitaliy Shibaev! For me it is working again. Seems like some internal google problems.

Comment: It looks fixed now, i can log in on here and across several applications

Comment: not working 30 minutes ago, now working...but still not working using a different internet provider.

Comment: Same error also in Asia (Israel) when using https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also don't have the rep yet to comment. But I have been noticing this issue today also.
All of my sites that use Google oauth (different tokens) are returning 500 errors after choosing the google account you want to log in with.

```
500. That’s an error.

There was an error. Please try again later. That’s all we know.
```

I checked the status page and I don't see any errors or any other reports of this https://status.cloud.google.com but it seems there is something going on since at least a few of us are seeing this. I have tried from multiple computers on different networks, and I had a friend try on a different google account and had the same issue. I am using the following gem in a rails app:

```
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2", "~> 0.2.1"
```

Edit: That page has now been updated with an notice on the bottom.

```
We are investigating an issue with Authentication services. We will provide more information by 07:30 US/Pacific.
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't post a comment as a guest but I have been noticing this as well. I have found that several refreshes sometimes bring up the authentication window, but I haven't actually been able to authenticate and connect yet. I am on the Eastern coast of NA trying to access GMAIL api.

Answer (score 1):

This started to happen to me this afternoon , it will occasionally work but most of the time it doesn't.

I have read this may be because you must now past through the oauth_verifier which has only just been changed, although it should not have just yet.

Source GarretMurray - https://twittercommunity.com/t/oauth-access-token-stopped-working-today/1630

He said that after adding the verifier it started to work again !

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced this, but the problem seems to have been resolved by Google.  I observed the errors happening on our application from roughly 13:42 - 14:28 UTC.

Answer (score 1):

As per https://status.cloud.google.com/

"We are investigating an issue with Authentication services. We will provide more information by 07:30 US/Pacific."

There is also subsequent post specifically on the Google Cloud App Engine service regarding this outage available at https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/appengine/16003.

Sources: See above.

Comment: Thanks for that link Brian! When we faced the issue I was looking for that exact page using google (how ironic) and couldn't find it.